# Difference between getscaleinstance and scale? (swing java)

Tags: java, swing

I saw a code that used getScaleInstance(x,x) to declare the scale. On the other hand, I also saw that some people used scale to declare the scale. What is the difference?

For example:

```
AffineTransform test= new AffineTransform();
test.scale(1.0,1.0) //1
test=AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0,1.0) //2
```

What is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the docs for you and have found that:

`scale()` - is a transformation of the matrix (inside `AffineTransform`) which is equal to following code:

```
AffineTransform test = new AffineTransform();
AffineTransform scale = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0, 1.0);
test.concatenate(scale);
```

As you can see from code above, firstly, we create a scale by calling `AffineTransform.getScaleInstance` and, secondly, we apply this scale to the "test".

So, `scale()` is a more concise way to do scalling. However, you should notice that `scale()` accepts two `double` params which descibe scale factors. Therefore, if you somehow calculate the scale as a `AffineTransform`, you should use `concatenate()` instead of `scale()`.

Summaryzing, these codes do the same thing, they are equal:

```
AffineTransform test = new AffineTransform();
test.scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

and

```
AffineTransform test = new AffineTransform();
test.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0, 1.0));
```

The first approach is unquestionable more concise than the second one.